# dplyr function is displaying an output in R markdown

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr

I am knitting a `R` markdown and the output looks fine for now, except for the problem that for some reason the knitted `html` shows the `dplyr::summarise` output too. Even after turning off `show messages` and `show warnings` the output persists. Please note that when I run the code without knitting, the console doesn't show this output.

How can I suppress this from showing in the `html`?

```
library(tidyverse)

# Used in main code to summarize data 
## Summarize data 
DF_Summarize = DF%>% 
  group_by(Code) %>% 
  summarise(Count_2020 = n())
```

Output showing in `html`. Now these are the summarized values from the dataframe.

```
##  [1]   2 179   5  47   6  92  33   1   6   5   3  13   6  99   1   7   4   4 423
## [20]  53  11   7 110  35 101   6   2   7   3   2   1   2   1   7   4   1   3   6
## [39]   3   5   1   3   7  13   1  40   1   7   2   1   3  18   1   2  10   1   2
## [58]   1  40
```

Comment: This doesn't look output from the summarised code. Are you printing something else in the markdown file?

Comment: You are working with chunks, aren't? If so, have you tried the chunk option `results="hide"` or `eval=FALSE`?

Comment: @LeonardoHansa, yes I am working with chunks, will these settings still generate a `ggplotly` present in that chunk?

Comment: Shouldn't output from `group_by` and `summarise` return a dataframe/tibble ? The output shown looks like a vector.

Comment: @RonakShah, yes you are right, the summarized data was stored in a `dataframe`. I don't really know from where this output in the knitted `html` is coming from, because running the code without knitting doesn't produced this sort of output in the console. Should I post my original code, it's a bit long though?

Comment: No worries, I found the mistake in the code. `DF$Count_2020` was present in the chunk as a line so that was causing it. You were right in your first comment Shah g; thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `echo = FALSE` in the `knitr` chunk label.

i.e.

````
```{r summarize, echo = FALSE}
## Summarize data 
DF_Summarize = DF%>% 
  group_by(Code) %>% 
  summarise(Count_2020 = n())
```
````

If you have other chunk output that you do want to display, just break up the chunks and use `echo = FALSE` in the one you want to hide, and leave `echo = TRUE` for the others.